# Is there a "Linux friendly" handset manufacturer for Android phones?

Tags: linux

My current situation is this: I use Mac OS X at home and Ubuntu Linux at work. My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S. Whenever I want to update my firmware *the intended way (i.e. using Kies, I am aware of Odin)*, I have to boot into an old Windows XP installation that I have lying around.

I was wondering if there is a handset manufacturer that embraces Linux. The Samsung phone seems to be just the wrongest choice I could have made with the windows-centric Kies software.

**Edit**: I should probably point out, that I live in Germany and I want to use a prepaid phone service without contract. Also, I am looking for a great "out-of-the-box" experience without too much hackery (i.e. without voiding the warranty).

**Edit2**: I was hoping to learn about brands which support Linux (like NVidia does with their proprietary drivers) or maybe learn about tools and techniques:

- Heimdall is a nice tool, but I don't feel that it has Samsungs approval, and I feel that using it might void the warranty.
- <strike>Over-The-Air Updates is something, that seems to be useful, but it won't work for me, as I don't have a contract with a cell phone provider.</strike> (*Edit 3:* This line is just non-sense, I receive OTA updates over wi-fi.)

Therefore I am still looking for some enlightenment about which direction I should go with my next phone.

**Edit 3:** After my recent purchase of the Samsung Galaxy S3 (I know... fool me once...), I would like to reopen the issue. My setup (except for the phone) is still the same (Mac OS X at home and Ubuntu Linux at home and at work).

In order to access the file system I either connect to an Ubuntu machine via USB. This is not ideal, because the drive size of the external sd card is not reported correctly, which makes me a little less confident in this solution.

On the Mac, I can only get iPhoto recognize the device in PTP mode. [Android file transfer](http://www.android.com/filetransfer/) does not recognize the device after the latest OTA firmware update.

As an alternative to the USB connection, I found [DigiSSHD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.digimead.digi.ctrl.sshd&hl=en) as a workaround to transfer files wirelessly.

After spending hours of looking for a better solution and adjusting my workflow to workarounds, I would like to ask again: **Is there a there a handset manufacturer that embraces Linux and provides native tools to interact with the device?**

I don't mind if the tool is proprietary or free as long as it works.

Comment: If it's any consolatino, Samsung seem to be moving towards OTA updates. The last 2.2.1 update to my Galaxy S added a "Software Update" option under Settings -> About Phone, and they've just recently pushed Froyo out to US Samsung Fascinates OTA. Your next Kies update could be the last.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to be tied to Windows-based Kies, Simply don't pick Samsung phones. Almost every other Android manufacturer's phones can be upgraded Over The Air without the need of an attached computer; for some reason Samsung's can't or won't do it.

Android was designed so it does not need to be attached to a computer as much as possible; Android was designed to sync data (address book, etc), installs software (market, etc), and do system updates over the air. Some manufacturer/carriers do not yet embrace this unfortunately, and is forcing your phone to be attached to a computer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the Over The Air updates. I was not aware of those. But won't that make me dependent on the carrier? I use a prepaid service (without contract) in Germany, I don't think that they will push updates to my phone.

Comment: Indeed, without a contract you may be locked out of official updates. Your option may be to root the phone and put on a custom ROM.

Comment: With an unbranded phone, I seem to get the updates directly from Samsung.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of a Kies alternative, but there is [Heimdall](http://www.glassechidna.com.au/products/heimdall/), an Open Source, Cross Platform, Odin alternative.

Comment: Heimdall is reverse-engineered, but very stable. It wasn't made with the help of Samsung, it was made in spite of Samsung. If the OP is looking for Linux/FLOSS *friendly* phones, it's not here.

Comment: I don't know about the OP, but I'm certainly in the market for a Linux friendly phone or tablet.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the linux support not only depends on the manufacturer.

In the case of the *Palms*, PalmOne only released desktop applications for Windows and Mac, but despite of that fact the linux community developed solutions like J-Pilot for example.

Answer (score 1):

OTA updates are a better solution. Not sure why Samsung sticks to some update utility while many other manufacturers use OTA update. HTC does OTA on my Hero and now on my Desire Z also. My Acer beTouch 130e required a utility. Not sure for other brands.

Comment: HTC does not release OTA updates for everything - the Desire Gingerbread ROM is an RUU and not ever going to be OTA.